# How to get account information using binance api?

Tags: api, cryptocurrency, binance

I'm trying to get my account information using Binance api.

curl request :

> curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY:
>   " -X
>   POST 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account' -d
>   'recvWindow=5000&timestamp=12345643&signature=8KhePoYVPdnw2T4Y38Yvurvr3U5Q59MYqvtg6kepFoMn9m3PvEnGeVjpV0Lmc5ab'

I get this

> ### Not Found

Probably I am not creating HMAC signature properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested example in bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

####API
APIKEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXyour api key here""
APISECRET="XXXXXXXXXXXXyour api secret here"

RECVWINDOW=5000 # 5 seconds

####GET ACCOUNT BALACE

TM=$(( $(date -u +%s) *1000))

GET_BALANCE_QUERY="recvWindow=$RECVWINDOW&timestamp=$TM"

GET_BALANCE_SIG=$(echo -n "$GET_BALANCE_QUERY" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac $APISECRET)

echo $GET_BALANCE_SIG
GET_BALANCE_SIG="$(echo $GET_BALANCE_SIG | cut -f2 -d" ")"
echo $GET_BALANCE_SIG

curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: $APIKEY" -X GET "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?recvWindow=$RECVWINDOW&timestamp=$TM&signature=$GET_BALANCE_SIG" | jq
```

=

Comment: You can use `code block` for `code section` for more info you check this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)